# How can I get the result of TeXForm[HoldForm[1 x^2 + 1 x + 1 == 0]] is x^2 + x + 1 ==0?

Tags: replacement, output-formatting

Sometimes, I get the situation when using `TeXForm` and `HoldForm`of a polynomial. E.g

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[1  x^2 + 1  x + 1 == 0]]
```

> 1 x^2+1 x+1=0

And then, I remove `1  x^2` to `x^2` and `1 x` to `x` by hand.

How can I tell Mathematica add a command to `TeXForm[HoldForm[1  x^2 + 1  x + 1 == 0]]` to get `x^2 + x + 1 ==0`?

Comment: `TeXForm[HoldForm[1   x^2 + 1   x + 1 == 0] /.   a_  x^b_. /; a == 1 :> x^b]`?

Comment: Or `TeXForm[HoldForm[1  x^2 + 1   x + 1 == 0]] /. HoldPattern[Times[1, a_]] :> a` in case `x` has a value.